# Capture Video of an HTMLelement with webcontrol not showing on screen c#

Tags: c#, html, video, iframe, webbrowser-control

I am trying to white an application that gets a url and find out all html5 canvas advertisement (i found out that iframes is the best HTMLElement that I can get) and take a video screenshot of the element.

I have to render the page (because it uses javascript calls to create the final page) using an in memory webbrowser control and then I find all iframes from document of the Webbrowser control (objDoc in the sample).

    `var aColl = from HtmlElement p in objDoc.Body.All
                        where Configuration.lstCanvas.Contains(p.TagName.ToUpper())
                        select p;`

For each element I have to capture a **screenshot** and a **video of the content of the iframe or even an html file that can represent the video later**.

In order to capture the image I use the following code (if i pass null to HTMLelement I get a full screen capture) as an extended metod of the webbrowser control.

```
public static Image GetElementImage(this WebBrowser web, HtmlElement elm = null)
    {
        try
        {
            IHTMLDocument2 idoc2 = web.Document.DomDocument as IHTMLDocument2;

            if (idoc2 == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            IHTMLElementCollection elementCollection = idoc2.all;

            if (elementCollection == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            IHTMLElementRender iHTMLElementRender;

            if (elm != null)
            {
                iHTMLElementRender = (IHTMLElementRender)elm.DomElement;
                if (iHTMLElementRender == null)
                {
                    return null; 
                }
            }
            else {
                iHTMLElementRender = idoc2.body as IHTMLElementRender;
                if (iHTMLElementRender == null)
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            // get the location and size of the element and create a bitmap
            // need a different interface

            IHTMLElement element = iHTMLElementRender as IHTMLElement;

            if (element == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            int elementWidth = element.offsetWidth;
            int elementHeight = element.offsetHeight;

            // Create a bitmap and render the element to it.

            Bitmap memoryBitmap = new Bitmap(elementWidth, elementHeight, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
            Graphics memGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(memoryBitmap);

            IntPtr memDC = memGraphics.GetHdc();

            iHTMLElementRender.DrawToDC(memDC);
            memGraphics.ReleaseHdc(memDC);

            Image r = (Image)memoryBitmap.Clone();
            memGraphics.Dispose();
            memoryBitmap.Dispose();
            return r;
        }
        catch // (Exception ex)
        {

            return null;
        }
    }
```

I haven't found a way to take a video capture of the element. 
I try to grab the content of the iframe as html (in order to save it and use it for latter) but I come out with some issues:

- The url is not always an attribute of the iframe (it changes from the javascript)
- Cross Domain scripting is not letting me to gram the html
- The file that I download is not allways reproduces the content of the iframe

Do you have any suggestion either on getting the html code or the video?

Thanks in advance